# EWS. UpdateItem. Why doesn't ChangeKey change?

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In EWS `ItemId` tag has `ChangeKey` attribute. This is what Exchange documentation says about this attribute:

> When you work with items in Exchange, another value to keep in mind is the ChangeKey attribute. This value, in addition to the item ID, is used to keep track of the state of an item. Any time an item is changed, a new change key is generated.

So in my app I'm performing `UpdateItem` operation. This is the XML that I send to the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
  <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <m:UpdateItem xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToNone">
     <m:ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
           <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADE3MTJkZWNlLTZiYWYtNDY4Yi1hNmM3LWU2MzY2ZDZjYWNhMQBGAAAAAACoXti5FFu8TJNLLS5k9vC8BwAcJDq8WkSCQ77jdOtyazgnAAAAAAEMAAAcJDq8WkSCQ77jdOtyazgnAACOg4SZAAA=" ChangeKey="`CQAAAA==`" />
           <t:Updates>
              <t:SetItemField>
                 <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:IsRead" />
                 <t:Message>
                    <t:IsRead>false</t:IsRead>
                 </t:Message>
              </t:SetItemField>
           </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
     </m:ItemChanges>
  </m:UpdateItem>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please note that `ChangeKey` is `CQAAAA==`. And this is the response that I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Header>
  <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="1365" MinorBuildNumber="1" Version="V2_23" />
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <m:UpdateItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
     <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:UpdateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
           <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
           <m:Items>
              <t:Message>
                 <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADE3MTJkZWNlLTZiYWYtNDY4Yi1hNmM3LWU2MzY2ZDZjYWNhMQBGAAAAAACoXti5FFu8TJNLLS5k9vC8BwAcJDq8WkSCQ77jdOtyazgnAAAAAAEMAAAcJDq8WkSCQ77jdOtyazgnAACOg4SZAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAAA==" />
              </t:Message>
           </m:Items>
           <m:ConflictResults>
              <t:Count>0</t:Count>
           </m:ConflictResults>
        </m:UpdateItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:UpdateItemResponse>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see the returned change key is still `CQAAAA==`. Why hasn't it changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read/unread status is technically not part of the message itself; it is stored separately. That is how per-user message status is implemented in the PF store. folders.

If you modify any other property, the change key will change.

Comment: Yet when I change read/unread status for the first time after a message was created the change key does change. It is subsequent updates of the read/unread status that leave the change key unchanged. How is that?

Comment: Don't know. The store provider is free to adjust other properties. Exchange frequently does that for the newly created messages.